# Detect First Alphabetic Character

Tags: php, if-statement

This is probably easier than I am making it out to be but I am looking to determine whether a entry from a user form contains a alphabetic character as the "first" letter only.

Example User Input:

```
<input type="text" name="faa_id" size="50" value="<?php echo $_POST['faa_id']?>" />
```

Example Form Processing

```
$faa_id = trim(strtoupper($_REQUEST['faa_id']));

if $faa_id = "string with any character except "N" in the FIRST position" {
   show URL-1; }

 else {
   show URL-2; }
```

Context: 
   Data will be Aircraft Registration Numbers.  Usually we enter them in our form without the default "N" (i.e. 345FR , not N345FR) but not all registration number start with N.

For example EJA345 is an aircraft callsign shown in place of generic N#, not registration number OR C-YEHE which is a Canadian Registration Number)

I know how to strip the first letter IF it were an "N" but I don't know how to detect if the first letters are alphabetic.

I suppose I would need to determine if first character is a alphabetic character first 
    then check to see if it is a "N".

If not an "N", then URL 1 but if it is an "N" then URL 2

My code will hard code the URL similar to this:

Example URL-1
    http://www.trackmyflight/N

Example URL-2
    http://www.trackmyflight/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out regex, it was made for looking up strings for expressions (REGularEXpressions):

```
$pattern = '/^[nN].*$/';
```

You can check it on [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/).
Just type a word which starts (or doesn't) with a N and put the pattern in the box after 'Expression'

In PHP you can check it with http://php.net/preg_match.
The code should look like this:

```
$temp = preg_match($pattern, $faa_id)
if($temp === false)
{
   //If an error occurs
}
else
{
   if($temp == 0)
   {
     return URL1;
   }
   else
   {
     return URL2;
   }
}
```

Comment: I defined $faa_id="N34RE" along with the rest of your code and I get the error: WARNING preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash on line number 48

Comment: Sry, my fault. Mixed up the paramteres, just change `preg_match($faa_id, $pattern)` to `preg_match($pattern, $faa_id)`

Comment: Also added Delimiters in the pattern

Comment: I made a few modifications to fit my needs a little better however, your example works...Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the string as an array:

```
if ($faa_id[0] != "N")
{
    // do your show URL-1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
$char = "A";

echo preg_match('/[A-Z]/',$char); // true
```

this checks if $char is equal to ONE captital letter.

Comment: Thanks...I don't need to know if there is one capital letter.  Maybe I don't follow.    I think I can make this less complicated to explanin,  I am trying to determine if the first letter is an "N" ... if so, then go to URL-1...if not then use URL-2

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
echo preg_match('/[A-Z-[N]]/',$faa_id[0] ); // true
```